# Firebase auth otp autofill flutter,sms_autofill package issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, autofill

I have made a simple code where i get verifyphonenumber otp from firebase but i want it to autofill in my textfeild i have used sms_autofill package but it require app signature in the sms but firebase sends 'APP_NAME' in the sms with code instead of the signature,as we cant edit firebase sms formate is there any way to auto fill otp in PinFieldAutoFill widget or any other textfeild
please help,can we edit sms_autofill.dart to change the signature requirnment to app name

Comment: '958686 is your verification code for otp-autofill-49b5d.firebaseapp.com.' This is the message firebase sends
'ExampleApp: Your code is 123456
FA+9qCX9VSu'
and this is the formate required for sms_autofill package

Comment: Do you have found any solution for this? How can we got '958686 is your verification code for AppSignature(rhaid122)?